# isset() not giving expected results

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form

```
<form action="addnote.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="tid" <?php echo"value='$id'"; ?> >
    <div class="input_fields_wrap1">
        <label>Note</label>
        <input type="text" id="coa" name="notes[]" >
        <button class="add_field_button1">Add More Notes</button>
    </div>
    <label>Next call date</label>
    <input type="date" name="call" >
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="example-text-input"></label>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <input input type="submit" value="Submit " >
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

and this is the php code

```
<?php
    include 'db.php';
    $id=$_POST['tid'];
    $notes=$_POST['notes'];
    if(isset($_POST['notes']))
    {
        for($i=0;$i<count($notes);$i++)
        {
            $sql="insert into notes (lead_id,note) value ('$id','$notes[$i]')";
            $var=mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        }
    }
    if(isset($_POST['call']))
    {
        $call=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['call']);
        $sql="update lead set `call`='".$call."' where lead_id='$id'";
        $var=mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    }
    header("Location: remove_lead.php");
?>
```

Now, even if I don't fill the `date` or `notes` text box, `date` still gets updated to `0000-00-00` and an empty note is stored in database.

But what I want is: If I don't fill one or both of them, then nothing should happen on php. Did I use `isset()` correctly?

I changed as suggested but no use

```
if(!empty($_POST['notes'])&&isset($_POST['notes']))
{
    $notes=$_POST['notes'];
    for($i=0;$i<count($notes);$i++)
    {
        $sql="insert into notes (lead_id,note) value ('$id','$notes[$i]')";
        $var=mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
}
}
if(!empty($_POST['call'])&&isset($_POST['call']))
{
    $call=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['call']);
    $sql="update lead set `call`='".$call."' where lead_id='$id'";
    $var=mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
}
```

Comment: Within `<input input type="submit"`  `<input input` `<-------` typo

Answer (score 3):

[`isset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) does not check for [`empty()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) it does only check whether the variable or array or object is **set**.

you need to check for `empty`.

```
if(isset($_POST['notes']) && !empty($_POST['notes']))
```

Comment: Just using empty is enough, don't need those 2 conditions. `if(!empty($_POST['notes'))`

Answer (score 2):

#### EDIT:

The problem is not with your use of [`isset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php).

**DATE PROBLEM:**

The problem is in this line of code.
`$call=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['call']);`

Change it to `$call=$_POST['call'];`

DO NOT USE `mysqli_real_escape_string()` on date values.

**NOTES PROBLEM:**

```
for($i=0;$i<count($notes);$i++)
        {
            $sql="insert into notes (lead_id,note) value ('$id','$notes[$i]')";
            $var=mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        }
```

If `lead_id` is a primary key or unique you wont be able to insert it twice, or have multiple `lead` with the same `lead_id`. Only one will be inserted. Insert and update will only give you one `note`.

*also:* There is a typo in your form. in the `<input input type="submit" value="Submit " >`.

*also:* The code below works.

`<input type="hidden" name="tid" <?php echo"value='$id'"; ?> >`.

But consider changing it to:

`<input type="hidden" name="tid" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" >`

Answer (score 0):

`isset()` is used to check whether that variable has been set or not and it doesn't concern with empty value. If it found `notes` input type with blank value still it will make condition true.

You need to check `if(isset($_POST['notes']) && $_POST['notes']!='')`

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this. Proper use of isset and proper use of empty function.

```
<?php
        include 'db.php';
        $id=isset($_POST['tid']) ? $_POST['tid'] : '';
        $notes=isset($_POST['notes']) ? $_POST['notes'] : '';
        $call = isset($_POST['call']) ? $_POST['call'] : '';
        if(!empty($id) && !empty($notes))
        {
            for($i=0;$i<count($notes);$i++)
            {
                $sql="insert into notes (lead_id,note) value ('$id','$notes[$i]')";
                $var=mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Something was empty";
        }
        if(!empty($call))
        {
            $call=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['call']);
            $sql="update lead set `call`='".$call."' where lead_id='$id'";
            $var=mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Call was empty";
        }
        header("Location: remove_lead.php");
    ?>
```

EDIT :- You have a non-working form as well

```
<form action="addnote.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="tid" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" >
    <div class="input_fields_wrap1">
        <label>Note</label>
        <input type="text" id="coa" name="notes[]" >
        <button class="add_field_button1">Add More Notes</button>
    </div>
    <label>Next call date</label>
    <input type="date" name="call" >
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="example-text-input"></label>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <input input type="submit" value="Submit " >
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

I'm not sure how you're getting the variable $id though.

Comment: How will it work if you have a non-working form? Check your form.

Answer (score 0):

`isset()` only checks if a variable exists or not

and you will have to use `empty()`, it checks that is there any value in it or not?

So change your `if` statements like so

```
if(isset($_POST['notes']) && !empty($_POST['notes']))
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot check variable is empty by `isset();`. You have to use `is_empty();` method to find it.